# Question regarding $\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\}$.

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms

Based on the [Laplace Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Computation_of_the_Laplace_transform_of_a_function%27s_derivative) page in Wikipedia, we can find the function $\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\}$ by solving $\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}$ using Integration by Parts:

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)\} &= \int_{0^-}^{\infty} e^{-st} f(t) \ dt \\ \\
&= \left[\dfrac{f(t)e^{-st}}{-s} \right]_{0^-}^{\infty} - \int_{0^-}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-st}}{-s} f'(t) \ dt \\ \\
&= \left[-\dfrac{f(0^{-})}{-s} \right] + \dfrac{1}{s}\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\} \ ,
\end{align*}

and isolating $\mathcal{L}\{f'(t)\}$. But on the second line, we evaluate $\left[\dfrac{f(t)e^{-st}}{-s} \right]_{0^-}^{\infty}$ as

\begin{align*}
\left[\dfrac{f(t)e^{-st}}{-s} \right]_{0^-}^{\infty} &= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left[\dfrac{f(t)e^{-st}}{-s} \right]_{0^-}^{N} \\ \\
&= \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \left[\dfrac{f(N)e^{-sN}}{-s} - \dfrac{f(0^-)e^{-s(0^-)}}{-s} \right] \\ \\
&= \left[0 - \dfrac{f(0^-)}{-s} \right] \\ \\
&= \left[ - \dfrac{f(0^-)}{-s} \right] \ ,
\end{align*}

assuming that $s > 0$. My question is, how is it true that $\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{f(N)e^{-sn}}{-s} = 0$ for all real functions $f(N)$? What if $f(N) = N^N$? Wouldn't the first term diverge if that's the case?

Comment: Presumably we are assuming ${\cal L}\{f\}$ exists, so its integrand tends to $0$.